# SMB share connection error: "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found." but only on a certain Win10 machine, others work fine

Tags: networking, windows-10, samba, smb2, smbclient

I have a SMB "samba" share setup on my RPie3. All my other machines can connect to it fine, but my primary Win10 machine cannot. I have ruled out DNS, and also SMB verion (SMB2 is in use) so I'm stumped.

Update: This is just a retro gaming system. **I do *not* want or need this to be secure AT ALL, I just want it to work.**

This is what I get on a **working machine**, testing via CMD.exe:

```
C:\>ping RetroPie -4

Pinging RetroPie.myDomain.local [192.168.3.56] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.3.56:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 7ms

C:\>net view \\RetroPie
Shared resources at \\RetroPie

Samba 4.9.5-Debian

Share name     Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
configs        Disk           configs
homes          Disk           Home Directories
roms           Disk           roms
splashscreens  Disk           splashscreens
The command completed successfully.
```

...and here are the same tests from my **non-working Win10 machine**:

```
PS C:\> ping -4 RetroPie                                                                                             
Pinging RetroPie.MyDomain.local [192.168.3.56] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.56: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.3.56:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 7ms, Average = 5ms
PS C:\> net view \\RetroPie
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.

PS C:\> net view \\192.168.3.56
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

EDIT1:
Things I have ruled out:

1. Windows firewall
2. Windows Defender anti-virus
3. SMB1 being in use (temporarily enabled it on my Win10 machine)

EDIT2 - Here are my `smb.conf` files (there are 2 and it's unclear which is needed, so I'm including both - note that all lines starting with a `#` comment have been removed for brevity's sake):

pi@retropie:/ $ cat .**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
   workgroup = drewz.local
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = SMB2
   server max protocol = SMB2
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
[roms]
comment = roms
path = "/home/pi/RetroPie/roms"
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = pi
[configs]
comment = configs
path = "/opt/retropie/configs"
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = pi
[splashscreens]
comment = splashscreens
path = "/home/pi/RetroPie/splashscreens"
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = pi
```

pi@retropie:/ $ cat **/usr/share/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
   workgroup = drewz.local
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = SMB2
   server max protocol = SMB2
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108088/discussion-on-question-by-kidacrimson-smb-share-connection-error-system-error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to the problem is based on an answer to the post
[Can not connect to share (system error 1272)](https://superuser.com/questions/1280365/can-not-connect-to-share-system-error-1272/1451160#1451160),
although only part of that answer was required.

The following lines need to be updated in `smb.conf` :

```
   [global]
   client min protocol = SMB3
   client max protocol = SMB3
   restrict anonymous = 2
   encrypt passwords = true
```

The answer advised removing the line of `map to guest = bad user`,
although for the poster without this line the network share wasn't accessible.

Comment: This is a general problem with SAMBA, that there are too many parameters,
and that the viability of any combination of values is a matter of hit-or-miss,
requiring sometimes much trial and error.

Comment: Thank you very much, @harrymc! :)

Comment: This did *not* work for me! I have some Windows 10 machines (release version 1909 is fine) working ok, but those with the newest updates don't. None of the `smbd.conf` options in your answer did solve the problem for me. I tried with and without `map to guest = bad user`. Samba also complains that `encrypt passwords` is deprecated. I am running `smbd` `version 4.11.6-Ubuntu`.

Comment: @user643011: You should start a new post with your problem and the details of your setup and what you tried.

Comment: You are right I should make a new question post. However a complete reinstall of all clients instead of an upgrade already fixed the problem for me. I still don't know what was the root cause or why it worked again after downgrading back to 1909 or what is different about the completely fresh installs of Win 10 21H2, but it works for me now. Appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this - the error message 53 in Windows net command is not super helpful.  There are some old pages related to Netbios and the like which is not the case here.  If you are using Ubuntu or similar to mount nfsd you should google that.  ie this page  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-20-04

For me the /etc/exports was not configured correctly. I needed to add this (and reboot the linux system)

/mnt/TestFiles 172.16.16.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

Further there is no nfs logging by default.  To do that run this command.

rpcdebug -m nfsd -s proc

From this page: https://www.serverstack.com/blog/2012/11/21/debugging-nfs-file-access-on-server-and-client-side/index.html

> "You can now test logging on server by creating and deleting a file
> from an NFS client:
>
> [root@nfs-client ~]# cd /mnt/nfs && touch test && rm -rf test
>
> The debug messages will be logged on the NFS server to
> /var/log/messages by default. "